# Print to POS Display Unit

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Epson Display Unit (for the Point of Sale), and have it set up as a printer.  I can only get it to print what I want when I go to Printer Properties > Fonts (there is a test input box).

However printing from an app such as notepad yields no results.  I'm trying to get it to work with the p.o.s. app I made in Excel.  I found a COMM port communication script [here](http://dev.emcelettronica.com/serial-port-communication-excel-vba), but I can't get past the OPEN command.  Seems there's a "file in use".  I'd like to know if anyone else has had experience with this sort of thing.

Comment: Sounds like more of an O/S / hardware issue (since you can't print from something like Notepad, which should work as long as everything is set up correctly).

Comment: In other words, I would try to make it work the "standard" way first, i.e. through a printer driver. It's going to be a little difficult to send data to the printer yourself unless you have a manual for it (including any special codes the printer needs to work correctly).

Comment: Also, are you _positive_ that the COM settings are in agreement (on both the port and printer sides)?

Comment: If you can't print in something simple like Notepad, then Excel won't be able to help.

Looking at your link, you are both trying to open the COM port.

Using Excel to print POS stuff doesn't sound right.  What are you trying to do?  Why that way?

Also, adding some more detail on the type of printer may help (model number etc)

Comment: @Michael Todd, 3rd response


- I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but I checked the printer settings and the port being used. It's named something strange, but the description says "COM1" - and based on the error I got, it does recognize that it is the right port, but that it's inaccessible. If I try - say - COM2, I get a different error, one that states that it cannot find a device. 



@Christian Payne


- I'm just trying to send text to the Epson POS Display Unit. I don't necessarily need excel to do it, I just need to be able to do it SOMEHOW. pos.epson.com/products/DM-D110.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that your printer is connected to serial interface 1, provided that the serial interface parameters are correctly set, and you want to send a string of characters to that interface, you may try this ...

```
Sub WriteToCOM()
    Open "COM1:" For Output As #1
        Write #1, "ddd"
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Paste this code into an Excel VBA script and cycle thru it with F8 - it worked for me

You may replace "COM1:" by any existing "COMx:" or "LPTx:" as well (don't forget the semicolon!)

I am using this to control an Amateur Radio (setting the frequency) from an Excel table containing broadcast station names and their frequencies. I am of course sending special characters to my gear using the chr() function.

The Macro is tied to a control button. My Excel is Office 2003 (it worked already in Office97)

Good luck
MikeD

Comment: Thanks Mike!  That did the trick - but only after I removed the POS Display Unit from my printer list; apparently that's what was causing the "inaccessible" problem I was having earlier on.